# SAP GUI 7.20 Security Rules - How to 'Always Allow' Everything?

Tags: security, sap

The SAP GUI 7.20 comes with a list of security rules.

What is the best way to allow all access so that user's wont get any security prompts? I need a solution that can be applied to many users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These registry entries need to be added:

**32bit PC’s:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security

DWORD key SecurityLevel with a value of 0
DWORD key DefaultAction with a value of 0

**64bit PC’s:**

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SAP\SAPGUI Front\SAP Frontend Server\Security

DWORD key SecurityLevel with a value of 0
DWORD key DefaultAction with a value of 0

The SAP GUI Security Manual implies that this option is reset to default whenever a patch is applied to the SAP GUI.

Comment: Thanks after half day of investigation, uninstall/reinstall 5 times, delete manually registry and directory still the same, until I read your post :D Not it works perfectly

Comment: Feel free to vote up ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're an user without administrative privileges (no access to the registry, such as a corporate computer), you can open the SAP GUI client, click on the SAP menu icon (in the top-left corner of the SAP Logon window) and choose `Options`. In the dialog, go to `Security->Security settings` and change the option `Security Module->Status` to `Disabled`.

You may also choose the status to be `Customized` and click the `Security Configuration Dialog` button and change the `Default Action` option to `Allow`.

**Be wary though**, because disabling security checks are there for a reason, and allowing everything is a big risk in case something goes wrong.